Movie about a German man trying to get a 3rd eye
OK I saw this movie a few years ago on demand and I can't find anything about it on the internet, I'm hoping someone else has seen it.
So in the beginning this man comes to this family and asks them to hide him and he lives in their shed and eats animals and does all kinds of rituals trying to get a third eye on his forehead, and their house was covered in X's which is supposed to keep him out. I'm pretty sure its an independent low budget film.
It was in English, they all spoke English but I remember something about the family being German might have even taken place in Germany. It wasn't an old movie, but it was possibly in a much older setting because I remember something about being around the time of a war, although the movie had nothing to do with the war. 
That's all I really remember about it. If this sounds familiar in any way please answer.

Pretty much know what you're after, but just to be sure: Do you know the approximate year of release? The country\language?

It was in English, they all spoke English but I remember something about the family being German might have even taken place in Germany. It wasn't an old movie, but it was possibly in a much older setting because I remember something about being around the time of a war, although the movie had nothing to do with the war. If I had to guess I'd say it was released in the 2000s. I know I'm not much help lol but this is driving me crazy.

Sounds like you're describing the beginning of 2009 horror film 'Town Creek' AKA 'Blood Creek' AKA 'So what has Joel Schumacher been up to lately?'

In 1936, a German professor, Richard Wirth, is hosted by the Wollners, a family of German emigrants in West Virginia. The Wollners believe him to be a visiting scholar, but Wirth turns out to be a Nazi occultist who seeks a Viking runestone buried on their property. When Wirth reveals he wants to use it for evil, he is interrupted by the family, who trap him in their basement and bind him through a ritual that requires frequent human sacrifices.

Wirth is trying to grow a third eye and he's bound by signs that look like X's. The plot moves on to 2007 when two brothers battle him. Here's the trailer:




Yes!!! This is it! Thank you so much! (:
